# Display page created using panel programatically

Tags: panels

I am using Drupal 7 and Panel module.

I have created custom page using panel module. **page-welcome**

I want to render this page on the following url **user/%user/my-profile**

Is there any way to print page programatically..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the path to /user/%user/my-profile within Panels.  For an example of this, look at the "User edit template" override provided with Panels, which, if enabled, overrides /user/%user/edit.

To set the path in Panels, go to /admin/structure/pages, choose the page you wish to edit, click **Basic** under **Settings**, and set the **Path**.

The help text there states the following:

> The URL path to get to this page. You may create named placeholders
>   for variable parts of the path by using %name for required elements
>   and !name for optional elements. For example: "node/%node/foo",
>   "forum/%forum" or "dashboard/!input". These named placeholders can be
>   turned into contexts on the arguments form.